# XLINQ : how to exclude node in XML using XLINQ

Tags: linq-to-xml

hi i have the following xml

```
<students>
  <student>
    <id>12</id>
    <name>Mohsan</name>
  </student>
  <student>
    <id>2</id>
    <name>Ali</name>
    <address>
      <country>Pakistan</country>
    </address>
    <address>
      <country>India</country>
    </address>
    <parent>
      <id>12</id>
      <address>
        <country>Pakistan</country>
      </address>
    </parent>
  </student>
  <student>
    <id>3</id>
    <name>Azhar</name>
  </student>
</students>
```

i want to get the address of student only. not the address of its parent. i used this query

```
var stds = from std in doc.Descendants("student")
                select new
                    {
                        ID = std.Element("id").Value,
                        Name = std.Element("name").Value,
                        Address = from addr in std.Descendants("address")
                                    select addr.Element("country").Value
                    };
```

but this query returning me address of its parent too. which i dont want. note that a student can have multiple address. please tell me how to exclude the parent address at the time of retrieval..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `std.Elements("address")` instead of `std.Descendants("address")`